# Change value in one row after comparison with the next row in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows

```
Position  Chr     Score
10101   chr1        0   
4509    chr1        3.58051     
10745   chr1        0
2344    chr1        0
7165    chr1        -2.59335    
6752    chr1        -2.655688   
7441    chr1        0   
7588    chr1        -4.022041   
10671   chr1        0
```

If the z score has a non-zero value I would like to convert it to a zero only if the previous value was zero OR non-zero in a different direction (ie positive or negative).

For the above I would like the dataset to end up looking as follows:

```
Position  Chr     Score
10101   chr1        0   
4509    chr1        0
10745   chr1        0
2344    chr1        0
7165    chr1        -2.59335    
6752    chr1        -2.655688   
7441    chr1        0   
7588    chr1        0
10671   chr1        0
```

I figure I need an apply function but I dont know how to use it. Can anyone help?

Comment: how do you want to handle the endpoints?

Comment: Yes- the endpoints should beset to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I know this is going to look a little clunky, but it is a vectorized (sort of) solution so there's that.  You could also technically do this all in one line, but that would be one heck of a line!

first you set up the different vectors you will compare, "test" will be my replication of the score column

```
test<-c(0,3,0,0,-2,-2,0,-4,0)
#elements higher than element i, where i is between 2 and length(test)-1
higher<-test[3:length(test)]
#elements lower than element i, same definition as above
lower<-test[1:(length(test)-2)]
#our ith elements
mid<-test[2:(length(test)-1)]
```

then we can reset mid all at once via ifelse

```
#if i-1 != 0 and i-1 has the same sign as i, we keep i, else 0
newscore<-ifelse((lower!=0)&(sign(lower)==sign(mid)),mid, 0)
#[1]  0  0  0 -2 -2  0  0
```

then set the endpoints to 0 as you put in the comments, and reset score

```
newscore<-c(0,newscore, 0)
#[1]  0  0  0  0 -2 -2  0  0  0
df$Score<-newscore
```

here is an alternative to the ifelse provided above, which keeps all consecutive numbers of the same sign

```
newscore<-ifelse((lower!=0), ifelse(((sign(lower)==sign(mid))), mid, 0),
    ifelse(sign(higher)==sign(mid), mid, 0))
```

and when running all the previous code with the following test vector

```
test<-c(0,3,4,5,0,0,2,2,2,0)
```

and the alternative ifelse the result is

```
#[1] 0 3 4 5 0 0 2 2 2 0
```

Comment: OK. Thats almost there. Works quite nicely. The only thing is that if I have a negative score and then a positive score (and vice versa) then it will convert the first score to zero and keep the second score. What would be great is, in this situation, both were converted to zero.

Comment: @user3632206 ok so the rule is (when looking at element i) if i-1 == 0 or when either i-1 or i+1 is a different sign from i, change i to 0?

Comment: @user3632206 which rules take precedence?  Like the case where i-1 == 0 and the sign of i and i+1 are the same, or where sign of i-1 is different than i and sign of i+1 is the same as i

Comment: Hi It should be a) if the row preceding i has a non-zero number that b) is the same sign as i, then keep i-1.

Comment: @user3632206 ok I made the change, a little more simple now, why don't you try it out

Comment: OK thats definitely better. Is there a way of keeping all the scores rather than binning the first one. At the moment if the scores are, for example 0,3,4,5,0,0,2,2,2,0 then it produces 0,0,4,5,0,0,0,2,2,0. Is there a way of keeping all the consecutive numbers?

Comment: I think the way that could be done is if you kept i when either i-1 or i+1 was of the same sign.  Precedence is starting to become more important.  The 3 in your example is preceded by a 0, so in your previous rule it should be changed to a 0

Comment: Tricky. What about the rule being that if the preceding number (i-1) is nonzero, AND i is non zero, then keep both numbers as long as they have the same sign. However if i is non-zero but i-1 is zero then move to the next row

Comment: @user3632206 ok I think I got it this time, although it is only tested with one vector.  I think you can probably make your way from here